# MySQL Workbench displays the wrong table rows size

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench is not displaying the right table row size. Please see the screenshot, and take a look at "Table rows".

[image]

MySQL Workbench shows at "Table rows" `0`. This is clearly wrong. See Action output:

```
09:21:37    SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable  280672 row(s) returned  0.031 sec / 24.969 sec
```

The question: why is Mysql Workbench displaying the wrong table row size?

I assume that the big table size is the cause for the problem.

Comment: what is your MySQL Workbench version? Possibly a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100516

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0.26

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by clicking on the "Analyze Table" button, screenshot:

[image]

It updated the table details info, screenshot:

[image]